# Store database connection in python?

Tags: python, mysql, database, postgresql, database-performance

I have a script A (python script) which opens the database and executes some queries and then closes the database connection.

I am not sure how long will script A run it all depends on the load.

I have an other script B (shell script) which runs the script A in a while loop. Which means that script A will be always running.

My database uses almost 100% or more of my CPU. I think it is because of repeatedly opening and closing connection.

Is there any way to improve performance?

I am using MYSQL database, planning to move to PostgreSQL.

I want to store the connection in some place and use the same if it is active or create a new one. I am not sure how to do it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> *I think* it is because of repeatedly opening and closing connection.

Based on what evidence? Done any tracing/profiling to try to trace it?

All the Python interpreter starts won't help either. Overall this all this sounds very inefficient.

Personally I recommend getting rid of the shell script wrapper; do it in the same Python script. Connect once in the outer loop and re-use the same connection in each inner iteration.

You can't "save" the connection. When the script terminates, the connection closes.

You could use a connection pooler like PgBouncer to reduce the overhead of creating and destroying all those connections but it won't be as good as just doing everything within the single script.

Comment: This is great, but I want to use Python script for loading different data. If I get rid of shell script then I will be creating two copies of the same file, which I don't think be so efficient.

Comment: @JayakumarBellie Er... tweak the Python script to take *command-line arguments* so you can invoke it with different filenames from a thin wrapper? You don't have to copy a script to change its behaviour, you can use environment variables, command line arguments, standard input, and more.

Comment: The question is about the database connection. How will you manage it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a logical flag inside the script B and not execute A unless it has finish the previous run. You can activate the flag once you start script A and deactivate it at the end. This will prevent overlapping and executing A in parallel.

Comment: There is no overlapping of the execution.